# How to watch for changes in objects inside javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, javascript-objects

I am creating a Todo app using electron and vue.js

I have an array of objects named `items`. Each object have the following syntax:

```
{id: <Number>, item: <String>, complete: <Boolean>, starred: <Boolean>}
```

I want to save the `items` array in a file whenever any content (including object attributes) change inside the array for which I need to watch for the changes.

I have tried Vue's `watch`, but it only triggers when an object is added or removed and not when an object's attributes change.

Here's a screenshot of the program with devTools open. I added an item, `starred` it and `completed` it. So, I expect 3 console logs but I get only one (when the object is added).

[image: Todo App Screenshot]

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use deep to watch object changes:

```
watch{
  item: {
     handler(newValue, oldValue){
       // something
     },
     deep: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Vue.set() then the props of each item-object are reactive too.